# Jsf - alternative for rich:toggleControl in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces

I am migrating my application UI which is written in richfaces into primefaces.

We have a commandlink in a code which opens up a panel directly using rich:toggleControl inside a rich tab in rich tabPanel.

`<a4j:commandLink style="color:blue; text-decoration: underline; font-size:8pt;font-style: italic;" value="Yearly calculation link (click here)" >
<rich:toggleControl targetItem="@next" targetPanel="yearlyCalculationPanel" />
</a4j:commandLink>`

This command link opens the particular panel in an another tab directly.

Does primefaces have an alternate to this particular functionality?

Comment: No, nothing like this exists, but with a combination of an include and plain ajax update you can achieve the same

Comment: Is not enough simply update tab in command link and put additional logic as rendering condition on tab level?